# Wso2 Stream Mongo Datetime join query

Tags: mongodb, wso2, siddhi

I try to make a query between a stream (contains a datetime) and a store mongodb table on a datetime column.

```
define stream TriggerStream (lastexec string);

 @info(name = 'ExtractData')
from TriggerStream as e right outer join OFFRELOG as o
on o.lastmodified> e.lastexec   
select CLIC_OFFRELOG,lastmodified
insert into RECO_TEST;
```

I get no data from this query. Is there a way to cast datetime column in timsstamp format ?

Best regards,
Nicolas

Answer (score 0):

The above query works only if the column(lastmodified) is of type long which is matched to a timestamp column of BSON type of long.

Siddhi-store-mongodb does not support [date](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/method/Date/#Date) column out of the box. I have opened an [issue](https://github.com/wso2-extensions/siddhi-store-mongodb/issues/37) in the Github repository to track this support.